# How to convert to binary using XS+3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigint

I'm stuck with an issue on my webpage, I'm trying to convert to binary using the 2^n-1 system and can't work up a solution. I've been fine working with 8, 16 and 32 bits but when I try to convert a long (64 bit) then it doesn't work. Any help will be great!

I'm using Jquery on a HTML webpage. I don't know if it's allowed to post the link, but if there's not a problem then I'll link it in a comment. My Jquery code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#boton").click(function(){
  var var1 = bigInt($("#numero").val());
  var var3 = bigInt($("input[name='bit']:checked").val());
  var var3 = var3 - 1;
  var var4 = bigInt(2).pow(var3);
  var var5 = var1 + var4;
  if (var5!=0){
     var var2 = bigInt(var5).toString(2);
     $("#final").text("El numero es " + var2.match(/.{4}/g));
     $("#final").show();
  } else {
        $("#final").text("El numero es 0");
        $("#final").show();
       };
   });
});
```

If I try to convert for example the number 37 on 8 bits, then it would be 37+(2^8-1=128)=165 and would have to convert 165 to binary, showing 10100101. When I try to convert 37 on 64 bits, then it just shows 1 followed by a great number of zeros

Comment: What is that `bigint` function?

Comment: Your `var3 = var3 - 1` and `var5 = var1 + var4` are not computed using biginteger logic put rather with plain js number operators, which is probably the problem. Use the methods of your bigint library instead. You should also not need `bigInt(var5)` (as `var5` should already be a bigint instance) and change `var5!=0` into bigint comparison.

Comment: it was recommended by my teacher so I could work with big numbers. I have a radio button on my website, depending on which option you work with big numbers or small numbers. For 64 bit I had to add bigInt instead of parseInt.
This is the website btw: http://llupiano.atwebpages.com/tp1/index.html

Comment: Please post your `bigint` function or point out the library you are using.

Comment: I'm using Peter Olson's "https://peterolson.github.io/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [the methods](https://peterolson.github.io/BigInteger.js/#methods) that your bigint library exposes:

```
var var1 = bigInt($("#numero").val());
var var3 = bigInt($("input[name='bit']:checked").val());
var3 = var3.subtract(1);
//         ^^^^^^^^^
var var4 = bigInt(2).pow(var3);
var var5 = var1.add(var4);
//             ^^^^
if (var5.notEquals(0)) {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^
    var var2 = var5.toString(2);
    $("#final").text("El numero es " + var2.match(/.{4}/g));
} else {
    $("#final").text("El numero es 0");
}
$("#final").show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I really appreciate it. That worked like a charm and now I can move on my other assignments. Wish you the best Bergi